# Stored Procedure enhancement for updating columns in a subset

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

The purpose of this store procedure is to reach into a large database (test), query for a subset, and update a column value, but with a big constraint - I can only update one row at a time in order to avoid deadlocks because the database is large and used by many resources.

The code attempts to change the value of `test.[stat]` to 'R' if a subset is found with the corresponding stat values.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].testProcedure (@name NVARCHAR(10), 
                                    @num INT,
                                    @msg NVARCHAR(200) OUTPUT )

AS

BEGIN

  DECLARE @val1 NVARCHAR(10) 
  DECLARE @val2 INT

  SELECT  t.val1, t.val2, t.stat, 'N' rel
  INTO #temp
  FROM   dbo.test t
  WHERE  t.[name] = @name
    AND t.[stat] IN ('A','B')   
    AND t.[num] = @num
  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  BEGIN
    SET @msg = 'Nothing returned'
    PRINT @msg
    RETURN -1
  END

  SELECT @val1 = val1 FROM #temp where rel = 'N'

  SET @msg = ' val1: ' +  @val1 + ' '

  WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from #temp WHERE rel = 'N')
    BEGIN
        SELECT @val2 = val2 FROM #temp where rel = 'N'

        UPDATE t
        SET [stat] = 'R'
        FROM   dbo.test t
        WHERE  t.val1 = @val1 AND t.[stat] IN ('A', 'B') AND t.val2 = @val2

        UPDATE #temp
        SET rel = 'Y'
        WHERE val2 = @val2

        SET @msg = @msg + ' - ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@val2),' ')  
    END

  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempd') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

  PRINT @msg
END
```

Any help on how to improve this code will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are constrained to updating only one row at a time? Generally that's the least efficient method of performing writes on table rows. The only good reason that I can think of is to minimize locks (usually at the expense of execution time).

Comment: Exactly that. The database is large and needed by plenty of resources, so it is to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Makes sense. I would suggest to add this clarification into your question.

Comment: Is this your real query? It looks very much like example code to me, and `SET [stat] = 'R', FROM   dbo.test t` (line 35-36) would raise a syntax error. Please clarify, as example code is off-topic on this site. If this is not the real, working code, please update the question to contain the real code.

Comment: It is my real code, I just changed all variable names.

Comment: Can't you simply use a cursor instead of a WHILE/EXISTS loop? I might not improve overall performance, which is dominated by the row-by-row processing...

Answer (score 2):

#### Anonymized code

Object/variable names should tell us something about what they actually mean. For instance, these variables:

```
  DECLARE @val1 NVARCHAR(10) 
  DECLARE @val2 INT
```

What does val1 and val2 actually stand for? In fact everything in the query looks like example code, so it leaves us to guess what the code is actually designed for.

---

#### `SELECT INTO #table`

You would most likely get performance improvements with regards to that temp table if you created it manually instead of using `SELECT ... INTO`. That would at least let you create some indexes on it. I've gained huge performance improvements with that technique in the past so I strongly recommend explicitly creating your temp tables along with indexes for performance-critical queries.

---

#### Cursor

You would likely get better performance in row-by-row operations if you used a cursor, instead of doing an update both to the source table and the temp table in a while loop. See [cursors on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) for reference.

---

#### Print @msg

I'm not really sure why you would print the `@msg` variable. According to your question, the purpose of the code is:

> The code attempts to change the value of test.[stat] to 'R' if a subset is found with the corresponding stat values.

So printing that message to the console seems like a waste of resources. I notice you are returning `@msg` as output anyways, so if the calling code needs that, it's easy to get it without printing it to the console.